# TestCase - Exception not raised in with statement when mocking __enter__

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, with-statement

I'm trying to test a Python method containing a `with` statement. The code inside the `with` statement can raise an `RuntimeError`. The test I'm talking about tests if the `RuntimeError` is raised.

The `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are heavy (typically open and close SSH connections), and I mock them when testing.

Here is a simplified definition of the method I want to test:

```
# client.py
class Client():
    def method_to_test():
        with self:
            raise RuntimeError()
```

For clarification purpose, I omitted the definition of `__enter__` and `__exit__`, and removed all the code in `method_to_test` which was not involved in the current issue.

To test this method, I mock `__enter__` and `__exit__`, and check if `RuntimeError` is raised:

```
# tests.py
from django.test import TestCase
import mock
from .client import Client

class ClientTestCase(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('mymodule.client.Client.__enter__')
    @mock.patch('mymodule.client.Client.__exit__')
    def test_method_raises_Runtime(self, mock_exit, mock_enter):
        mock_enter.return_value = None
        client = Client()
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
            client.method_to_test()
```

This test fails with: `AssertionError: RuntimeError not raised`

If I do not mock `__enter__`, the `RuntimeError` is raised. Why does mocking `__enter__` makes this test fail?

Comment: What is `mymodule`? I don't think you mocked the right thing.

Comment: @chepner mymodule is the module where client.py and tests.py live. When using pdb, I clearly see that `self.__enter__` and `self.__exit__` type are MagicMock, meaning I patch on the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen in PEP343 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

```
The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
```

As `self.__exit__` is a `MagicMock` in `Client.method_to_test`, `self.__exit__` returns a `MagicMock`, evaluated as `True`. The `RuntimeError` is swallowed.

The fix is easy. `self.__exit__()` as to return `None` instead of a `MagicMock`:

```
# tests.py
from django.test import TestCase
import mock
from .client import Client

class ClientTestCase(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('mymodule.client.Client.__enter__')
    @mock.patch('mymodule.client.Client.__exit__')
    def test_method_raises_Runtime(self, mock_exit, mock_enter):
        # __exit__ returns None, evaluated as False
        mock_exit.return_value = None
        mock_enter.return_value = None
        client = Client()
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
            client.method_to_test()
```